# I like to stuff things in my gut

Tags: riddle, wordplay, no-computers

What am I?

> I like to embrace pretty much everything in life,
>
> And I am obsessed with a popular essential oil.
>
> I chew on gum pretty much all day,
>
> And don’t drink a lot of water.
>
> I like to stuff things in my gut,
>
> And I give all of my kids the same name.
>
> I have signs dedicated to me,
>
> And it's probably because I am so adorable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My wife thinks it’s:

> A koala

because:

> “Gut” refers to its pouch. All its kids are named “Joey” (joeys are baby koalas). Also, koalas are apparently adorable.

and I can attest she didn’t use a computer. :-)

Comment: Your wife is correct! Good job! :D

Answer (score 2):

Is it...

> a truck?

```
I like to embrace pretty much everything in life,
```

> Trucks can be used to transport pretty much anything.

```
And I am obsessed with a popular essential oil.
```

> Petrol

```
I chew on gum pretty much all day,
```

> Tyre gum

```
And don’t drink a lot of water.
```

> Yes, you prefer petrol

```
I like to stuff things in my gut,
```

> Transporting stuff

```
And I give all of my kids the same name.
```

> All trucks from the same truck model have the same name

```
I have signs dedicated to me,
```

> Street signs

```
And it's probably because I am so adorable.
```

(this I don't know)

Comment: Very good guess, but incorrect! Keep guessing! :D